# Xamarin.Forms блок с фиксированными координатами

Tags: c#, xamarin, position, scrollview, fixed

Приветствую! Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Xamarin.Forms сделать блок, аналогичный поведению `position: fixed` в **HTML**? Т.е., например, есть контент, который скроллится, и над ним есть шапка, которая независимо от скроллинга всегда видна?
Пример: меню в нижней части экрана приложения **Вконтакте**.

Как я пытался сделать через Grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MobApp.TestPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Новости" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

        <ScrollView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout x:Name="NewsItems">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 1 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 1 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 2 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 2 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 3 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 3 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 4 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 4 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 5 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 5 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 6 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 6 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Новость 7 Заголовок" />
                    <Label Text="Новость 7 Текст" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Занятный феномен, который отнял у меня пару дней жизни) Задача и правда решается через Grid + ScrollView, всё прекрасно работает и из моего примера. Судя по всему у меня было что-то не так с эмуляторами. Всё началось с того, как я заметил, что эмулятор (Nougat 7.1) предоставляемый по умолчанию сразу после установки Xamarin, отображает скролл как нужно. Я смекнул, и начал копать. Все эмуляторы, которые создавал я (с любым апи от 4.4 до 7.0) - отображали скролл с описанным выше багом. Изменить/копировать или воссоздать такой же эмулятор как предоставляемый по умолчанию не получилось, менеджер эмуляторов ругался какой-то ошибкой. Я капнул еще глубже, это отняло много времени и нервов, но результат окупился:

1. Обновил Android SDK до 26 (последней) версии
2. Обновил Xamarin Android Emulator Manager до последней версии
3. Включил в BIOS технологию аппаратной виртуализации
4. Через диспетчер пакетов SDK для Android установил HAXM. Но так на самом деле он не устанавливается, а просто скачивается, нужно после    этого дополнительно найти его у себя на компьютере (у меня это в    C:\Program Files    (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) и запустить intelhaxm-android.exe
5. Всё. После этого созданные мной эмуляторы отображают все данные корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно именно меню, то это Tabbed Page.
Если блок, то вам нужно правильно скомпоновать элементы на странице.
Для прокручивающегося контента используйте ScrollView, который, к примеру, расположен на GridView вместе с другими элементами в ячейках.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В спецификации и мануалах говорится, что ScrollView крайне не рекомендуется вкладывать в другие контентные контейнеры. И GridView я так понимаю это контейнер исключительно в Android? Есть ли подобное кроссплатформенное решение? Я пробовал положить ScrollView в Grid, но контент в ScrollView все равно прокручивается так, будто он единственный на экране - заползает на верхние строки Grid и перекрывает их.

Comment: @Лев https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/ есть тут грид для вас. покажите код.

Comment: Добавил код в своё исходное сообщение. [Вот загружается страница](http://shot.qip.ru/00UU0v-695nqPrPk/), тут всё как надо, но стоит начать [скроллить](http://shot.qip.ru/00UU0v-595nqPrPl/), как возникает описанная выше проблема.

Comment: @Лев не понимаю, что Вас не устраивает. прокрутка идет. "Новости" остается на месте.

Comment: Интересно. На каком эмуляторе смотрите? Я на Android 4.4 API 19, и прокрутка наезжает на заголовок "Новости", это видно из предоставленного мной скриншота.